# libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: cuda, pytorch, torchvision

I'm using Pytorch  under Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to `import torchvision`, but I get an error `libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Someone could help to fix it? Thanks.

The infos below are detailed error logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-6dd351122000>", line 1, in <module>
    import torchvision
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torchvision import models
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/models/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import detection
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .faster_rcnn import *
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/faster_rcnn.py", line 7, in <module>
    from torchvision.ops import misc as misc_nn_ops
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/ops/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .boxes import nms, box_iou
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/ops/boxes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torchvision import _C
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-677acbcfae34>", line 1, in <module>
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torchvision import models
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/models/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import detection
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .faster_rcnn import *
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/faster_rcnn.py", line 7, in <module>
    from torchvision.ops import misc as misc_nn_ops
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/ops/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .boxes import nms, box_iou
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/ops/boxes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torchvision import _C
  File "/home/x/pycharm-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `anaconda`, the following may fix your problem.

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit==9.0
```

---

You can also try the followings.

Make sure the CUDA version is 9.0. And add the following 2 lines to `~/.bashrc`.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then, run:

```
source  ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following lines to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf`

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

And run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I didn’t use conda yet, is it necessary to install it to fix this problem?

Comment: No, it is just an alternative and in many cases less painful to setup environments.

Comment: Just wondering i have installed cuda 10.0, why it can’t find libcudart 9.0?

Comment: Did you install PyTorch for CUDA 9.0 or 10.0?

Comment: maybe I should reinstall pytorch for cuda 10.0

Answer (score 2):

using `anaconda`, torch version is:

```
pytorch==1.1.0
torchvision==0.3.0
cudatoolkit=10.0
```

has the same problem, and fix it by changing `torchvision==0.3.0` to `torchvision==0.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your CUDA version with one of these:

   ```
    nvidia-smi
    nvcc -V
   ```
2. Check your Pytorch CUDA version like this:

   ```
    python
    import torch
    torch.version.cuda
   ```
3. The versions should match. Otherwise you need to either upgrade/downgrade your CUDA or do the same but for Pytorch. The error `libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` means that the versions don't match. You have Pytorch for CUDA 9.0, but your CUDA is another version.
4. To solve this install Pytorch with the correct CUDA version like this:

   ```
    conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
   ```

NOTE: Replace the Pytorch and the CUDA Toolkit version with the desired ones. Check the available versions [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/).

5. If applicable, rebuild your Pytorch:

   ```
    rm -rf build
    python setup.py develop
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a generic solution *independent* from the cuda version.

1. The goal to set the correct path to the cuda library which is called `libcudart.so.<version number>`.
2. We find this path by `sudo find / -name 'libcudart.so.<version number>'`
3. We must add the path to the folder (not to the file) containing `libcudart.so.<version number>` in the .bashrc :

   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to libcudart.so file>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score -2):

Try the following command

```
pip3 install torch===1.2.0 torchvision===0.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I am using CUDA Version: 11.6 and this solved my error.

Source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25173#issuecomment-524802888